# Css vertical align span inside div

Tags: html, css

So I am trying to vertical align and horizontal a textbox span inside a parent div, the problem is it can valign or halign fine, not both. If it is a one line text it works fine, but if it is a long paragraph that takes multiple lines of the parent div, it does not vertical align.

```
.objprevicnt {
position: absolute;
margin: 0;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
width:inherit;
height:50px;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

also I am changing the text dynamically

```
document.getElementById("myid").innerHTML = 'some text';
```

so it should recenter as appropriate.

You would think this would be a simple thing, vertical and horizontal centering of a box inside another box, should work regardless of the size of text inside the box.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think these CSS properties will work. Please try this.

```css
#parent_div{
display:flex;
align-items:center;
direction:column;
}
#child_element{
display:flex;
align-self: center;
}
```

Comment: great that takes care of the vertical, but it is horizontaly left justified

Comment: nevermind i figured it out, thanks, this seams to be the solution

Comment: Glad that I can help :)

Answer (score -1):

The easiest way to center an element inside a parent element would probably be using flexbox:

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.child {
  display: block;
}
```